# How to iterate array inside the object using mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I tried to iterate array inside object key value using mongodb.but its not working.how to achieve it.

**Database code**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.product.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "category",
    "localField": "id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "ordersetails"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "product_name": 1,
    "product_image": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$product_image", 0] },
    "ordersetails": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$ordersetails.name", 0] }
  }}
]).toArray()
```

Comment: It will not work if you have more than one records in ordersdetails.

Comment: @RishabhGarg Please check the `localField` and the `foreignField`. It is targeting to `_id` of the other collection which means the record is unique. Hope you will get it.

Comment: @Fanpark Yes, True. Missed the _id.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple object in orderdetails array then you can use the following query :

```
db.product.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "category",
        localField: "category_id",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "ordersetails"
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        product_name: 1,
        product_image: { $arrayElemAt: ["$image", 0] },
        ordersetails: 1
      }
    }, 
    {
       $unwind: "ordersetails"
    },
    {
      $project: {
        product_name: 1,
        product_image: 1,
        ordersetails: "$ordersetails.name"}
      }
    }, 
  ]).toArray();
```